# ArrayList comparison with a recursive method

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist

I am writing a method that calls a recursive helper method to basically see if the elements of two `ArrayList`s are equal and return true if so. I realized, when testing, that the method returns true even if the two `ArrayList`s are of same lengths and same first and last elements but different elements in between, which I do not want. I think the method works otherwise. Any suggestions or hints on how I could fix this?

```
public static boolean isEqual(ArrayList<T> list1,
        ArrayList<T> list2) {
    return isEqual(list1,list2,0);
}

private static boolean isEqual(ArrayList<T> list1,
        ArrayList<T> list2, int n) {
    if (n==0 && list1.size()==0 && list1.size() == list2.size())
        return true;
    else if (n>=list1.size() || n>=list2.size())
        return false;
    if (n<list1.size() && list1.size() == list2.size()) {
        if (list1.get(n).equals((list2.get(n)))) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return isEqual(list1, list2, n + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
if (n<list1.size() && list1.size() == list2.size()) {
    if (list1.get(n).equals((list2.get(n)))) 
        return true; // don't return true here, since you just tested one element
    else
        return false;
}
return isEqual(list1, list2, n + 1);
```

Change it to :

```
if (n<list1.size() && list1.size() == list2.size()) {
    if (!list1.get(n).equals((list2.get(n)))) 
        return false;
}
return isEqual(list1, list2, n + 1);
```

You'll have to add another stopping condition in which you return true, though.

```
if (n == list1.size() && list1.size() == list2.size())
    return true;
```

This means that the lists have the same length, and you already compared all the elements successfully.

You should probably add a check on the list sizes and return immediately false if the lists have different sizes. There's no point in doing any recursive calls in this case.

```
if (n==0 && list1.size() != list2.size())
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, here's shorter recursive version:

```
public static <T> boolean listsEqual(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) {
    return l1.size() == l2.size() && (l1.isEmpty() || listsEqual(l1, l2, l1.size()));
}

private static <T> boolean listsEqual(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, int size) {
    // l1.size() == l2.size() == size here
    return size == 0 || (l1.get(size - 1).equals(l2.get(size - 1)) && listsEqual(l1, l2, size - 1));
}
```